# Reference in survival analysis is not 0

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am conducting survival analysis, investigating the association between a binary `factor` (TRUE/FALSE) and all cause mortality. I use the `rms` package:

```
 > m <- cph(dead ~ factor, data=dta)
 >
 > summary(m)
 ...                  Low High ... Effect
 factor - TRUE:FALSE  1   2        0.14
```

In my interpretation, this means a HR of exp(0.14)=1.15 for those with `factor == T`.

`Predict(m)` gives me the estimates of the log Relative Hazard - and I would have assumed that it would be 0 for `FALSE` and 0.14 for `TRUE` - but this is not the case:

```
 > Predict(m)
 ...                   yhat
factor.1    FALSE   -0.0014
factor.2    TRUE     0.14
```

I have to admit that I don't understand this. If this is the relative hazard, what is it relative to? There are no missing data or values other than `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Why did you assume it would be 0?

Comment: As it is log(relative hazard) - shouldn't the reference be 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with what is taken to be the reference baseline hazard/survival curve for a Cox survival model.

A regression coefficient for a binary predictor in a Cox model, as in your first display, represents the log of the relative hazard *between* the 2 values of that predictor. That relative hazard is independent of the particular choice of baseline hazard, under the proportional hazards assumption.

The 2 values reported in your second display are for differences for *each* predictor from the *baseline* hazard at some *reference* condition. The choice of reference condition is software-specific. In the R `survival` package the default baseline hazard in the `basehaz()` function is at a "mean" value that makes no sense with a categorical predictor (as the help page acknowledges) but can make some internal calculations more reliable. Something like that seems to be going on here.

When you do full survival-curve predictions or predictions of differences between specified combinations of predictor values, the choice of baseline hazard cancels out. There is nothing to be concerned about from your second display.

Comment: Thank you! So the big question is really what reference is used and whether it can be changed.

Comment: @Gux one trick is always to specify desired combination(s) of _all_ predictor values if you don't know or don't accept the defaults. The software will then combine its own choice of reference with your choice of predictor values to give the correct corresponding survival curve(s) or differences in hazards among sets of predictor values. The help pages for the `rms` `Predict()` and `survplot()` functions show several examples of how to do that, as do Harrells' [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/).